# Progress bar in toolbar not taking entire width

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I need at add a custom layout in toolbar which has a progress bar. When I try to add progress bar to Toolbar. I get follwing:

[image]

But I am expecting:

[image]

Following is my toolbar Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme= "@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="15dip"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="1000"
        android:progress="500"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_color"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

How can I achieve image 2 appearance?

Comment: have you tried addng the progress bar bellow the toolbar? instead of inside of it? To me it looks like it is bellow the toolbar

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Actually I want to keep this view hidden until user presses a Drawer layout menu item. I have an Activity with fragments. When this view is visible, user is allowed to navigate to another fragment. What I want to do is keep this toolbar with progress bar as is and just replace the fragment. So I was adding it to toolbar so that it will stay as is.